# GCP Project Migration - Maintain IDs

Tags: google-cloud-resource-manager

I'm migrating a project from no organization to a new organization.  Will the project ID, dataset IDs, and any other IDs remain the same?  Are there any potential disruptions besides those mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#migrating_projects_no_org)?

Comment: After you review the Google document, do you have any resources not covered by the list in that document? I think your question is too broad and should clearly define what resources your project has. Someone with experience with a specific resource might have information.

Comment: @JohnHanley, no, no resources not covered by that list.  Do you know if the product ID and dataset IDs would be maintained after the migration?

Comment: The Project ID will not change. I cannot answer for the Dataset IDs.

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentacion, [the project ID](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#before_you_begin) can only be modified when you're creating the project, after that you can not modify the project ID. So when you migrate your project to a new organization, the project ID will not change.

Regarding your question about [the dataset’s ID](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/move-datasets), once you create a dataset it can't be relocated, but you can make copies of a dataset, manually or using the [BigQuery Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/introduction). When you copy your dataset to a new location, you can choose to create the new dataset with the same ID or use a different one.

> To manually move a dataset from one location to another, follow this
> process:
>
> Export the data from your BigQuery tables to a Cloud Storage bucket in
> either the same location as your dataset or in a location contained
> within your dataset's location. For example, if your dataset is in the
> `EU` multi-region location, you could export your data to the
> `europe-west1` Belgium location, which is part of the EU.
>
> Copy or move the data from your export Cloud Storage bucket to a new
> bucket you created in the destination location. For example, if you
> are moving your data from the `US` multi-region to the
> `asia-northeast1` Tokyo region, you would transfer the data to a
> bucket you created in Tokyo. For information on transferring Cloud
> Storage objects, see Copying, renaming, and moving objects in the
> Cloud Storage documentation.
>
> After you transfer the data to a Cloud Storage bucket in the new
> location, create a new BigQuery dataset (in the new location). Then,
> load your data from the Cloud Storage bucket into BigQuery.